# Modify output of ping to text file into a single line

Tags: command-line, ping

I am using a loop and this command to display my ping result in a text file:

```
ping.exe -n 1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>> trace.txt
```

The result is 8 lines of code!

> Pinging xxxxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] with 32 bytes of data:
>
> Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=125
>
> Ping statistics for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:
>
> Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
>
> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>
> Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

I just would like to display the last line as I don't want a huge text file as result.

The perfect result would be:

> Ping 11oct2011 16h56 : Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds you would like tail.

```
ping test_server | tail -n 1
```

I got it with cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

With just cmd.exe from Windows 7, the following command should be able to achieve your expected output:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('ping -n 1 INSERTIPHERE ^| find "Minimum"') do @echo %TIME% %DATE% %a >> ping.txt
```

The output would be:

18:22:24.45 11/10/2011     Minimum = 13ms, Maximum = 13ms, Average = 13ms

Answer (score 1):

I like @bdecaf's answer, but prefer more useful output.

```
$ ping svcuat1.ec2 | sed '/PING/!d;N;s/\n/, /'
PING svcuat1.ec2 (172.31.16.60): 56 data bytes, 64 bytes from 172.31.16.60: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=91.171 ms
```

What it does is:

- "Not delete" (`!d`) the lines matching `PING` (meaning delete the rest)
- Append the next line of input to the pattern space `N`
- Swap the newline char with a comma and space `s/\n/, /`